# Where to implement conv2d for pytorch (which path and files)

Tags: python, pytorch

I only found the conv2d implement by torch.nn.functional.conv2d,and implemented by C.but I counld found which cpp implement it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THnD7.png)

I try to find the cpp which implement the conv2d in the pytorch files(find how to caculate the conv2d)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the implementation of `conv2d` in the main branch of the pytorch github repository.

The variations of the function conv2d and the convolution itself are defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp#L940)

Comment: If you believe the question is a duplicate, why did you decide to answer it anyway? Isn't this acting against your own advise?

Comment: I am lacking the "Close vote privilege" and interpreted this as the correct way according to community guidelines. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's not correct. You have the privilege to post comments. You can add the link to the question as a comment. Don't duplicate information that can already be found on the site.